# Alamofire insert body part text/plain with multipart-form/data

Tags: alamofire

i'm using Alamofire 4.0 in my iOS project

If i send UTF8 encoding to multipart form data, korea language will be broken in the server's database.

so I want to send not utf8 encoding

here my code

```
 Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

```
        for (key,value) in parameter {
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
        }

        for value in dataParameter.getDataParamtert() {
            multipartFormData.append(value, withName: "img_file", fileName: "jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        }},

                     to: urlString,
                     method: .post,
                     encodingCompletion: { result in

                        switch result {
                        case .success(let result, _, _):
                            result.validate(statusCode: 200..<400)
                                .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in

                                    let json = JSON(data: response.data!)

                                    if let result = json["result"]["data"].string{
                                        print(result)
                                    }
                                })

                        case .failure(let encodingError):
                            print("error:\(encodingError)")
                        }
    },paramteters:parameter)
}
```

```

is it possible to put parameter format in the bodypart with multipart-form/data ???  something like

```
 Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: {},parameters:paramter)‎ ..
```

please help me  .. thank u

Comment: which format you want to encode with, actually UTF-8 is 8-bit Unicode Transformation Format